# Take logic operation it self not only the boolean result as a input of function in PYTHON

Tags: python, function

In SqlAlchemy, I saw this type of expression:

```
s = select([users, addresses]).where(users.c.id == addresses.c.user_id)
```

It looks like it takes the logic operation it self not only the boolean result as an input. For example, if I want to build a function like:

```
def myfunc(argument): # I know its not right, I just want to show what I am suppose to do
    print(argument[key], argument[operation], argument[value])

myfunc(myage >= 10)

>> I want to get output like "myage", ">=" (or something similar), 10
```

Any one know how to do that?

Thank you

Comment: I believe SQLAlchemy does some operator overloading from this [architecture document](http://aosabook.org/en/sqlalchemy.html). (Scroll down to the section on `Python Operator Approach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [GWW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28099360/take-logic-operation-it-self-not-only-the-boolean-result-as-a-input-of-function#comment44574532_28099360) points out, this works by overloading the comparison operators to return something else than booleans. Here is a small example:

```
class col(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return [self.name, '<', other]


def myfunc(arg):
    print(arg)

myage = col('myage')
myfunc(myage < 10)
```

leads to

```
['myage', '<', 10]
```

The point is that the function (`myfunc`) only "sees" the evaluated result of the argument expression. But you can control how (for example) the "<" is evaluated by overriding the `__lt__` (less than) method of a class.

To make this work universally, you would have to override some more of the [special methods](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).